# A problem of Green's theorem in a plane

Tags: vector-analysis, greens-theorem

Verify Green's Theorem in a plane for

$$\ \int_C (\sin x - y^2)dx +(x-y^2)dy  $$ where $\ C $ is the boundary curve of the region  $R=\{(x,y)| y \ge x^2 + 1, y \leq2\}$.

Here $P=\sin x - y^2$ and $Q=x-y^2$.

$$\ \int \int_R (Q_x - P_y)dx dy = \int_{-1}^1 \int_{x^2+1}^2 
(1+2y)dxdy = ...=\frac{28}{5}. $$

$y = x^2 + 1$ is a parabola with vertex at $(0,1)$ and axis vertical, and the horizontal line $y=2$ cuts the parabola at $(1,2)$ and $(-1,2)$.

How to find the line integral $\int_C P dx +Qdy$ ? Please suggest.

I can evaluate the line integral along $C_1:$ $y=2$ and unable to evaluate along the boundary of the parabola $C_2$.

Please help

[image]

Comment: Haven't you just found it by Green's theorem?

Comment: @user1942348 Please fix your definition of the set $R$... As it is written, the set has two points and an empty boundary...

Comment: You just found it! Green's theorem states precisely that the line integral has the same value as the double integral you computed.

Comment: @PierreCarre Ok...I have drawn the region which is the inner part of parabola and $y=2$. Could you please correct my R as per the drawing

Comment: @PierreCarre I can evaluate the line integral along $y=2$ and unable to evaluate along the boundary of the parabola. Please help

Comment: @uniquesolution Using Green's theorem, I evaluate double integral, and now I want to verify Green's theorem by evaluating line integral too.

Answer (score 1):

So, I gathered that you wish to verify the validity of Green's theorem and that you are stuck on computing the line integral over $C_2$.

The parabola can be parametrized by $\gamma(t) = (t, t^2+1), t \in [-1,1]$. So, the line integral can be computed as

$$
\int_{-1}^1 1\cdot (\sin t - (t^2+1)^2) dt + \int_{-1}^1 2t \cdot (t-(1+t^2)^2)dt = \cdots = -\frac{12}{5}.
$$

Since the integral over $C_1$ is 8, you get the intended result.

Comment: Thanks a lot...